# Regex to match the multiple lines including new line

Tags: javascript, regex

regex for matching all the characters including new line.
regex to match the characters in between 1. and next new line till 2.

```
1.asfddfdf1#q23.wera
sdfdfd
asfdsf
2.asdds
asddf
asdd
asdd
asdd
asd
3.sdffgfdg
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This regexp will find all lines that start with digit on new line until the next digit on beginning of the line ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OOyiHK/1)):

```
data = '''1.asfddfdf1#q23.wera
sdfdfd
asfdsf
2.asdds
asddf
asdd
asdd
asdd
asd
3.sdffgfdg'''

import re

for lines in re.findall(r'^\d.*?(?=^\d|\Z)', data, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M):
    print(lines)
    print('*' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
1.asfddfdf1#q23.wera
sdfdfd
asfdsf

********************************************************************************
2.asdds
asddf
asdd
asdd
asdd
asd

********************************************************************************
3.sdffgfdg
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Could you please make it to work with JavaScript.
the regular expression is not working with Javascript in regex101.